# Creación de BBDD en python

Tags: python, sqlite3

estoy creando una especie de gestor de Base de Datos la cual permita crear datos, modificarlos, leerlos o borrarlos. Ya tengo bastante parte hecha, ahora mismo voy haciendo el boton de "crear" el cual creará los datos dentro de la tabla, pero al darle valores al cursor.executemany me tira error en la terminal

```
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 4, and there are 5 supplied
```

el tema es que le hice una tupla de prueba, la cual da los valores que hay en esa tupla

```
lista=["hola1", "hola2", "hola3", "hola4"]
```

pero me indica que tiene 4 statements cuando en realidad son 5, solo que el primero es null porque es un campo de IDs

```
cursoor.execute("""
CREATE TABLE USUARIOS (
ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
NOMBRE VARCHAR(50),
APELLIDO VARCHAR(50),
PASSWORD VARCHAR(50),
COMENTARIOS VARCHAR(100))
""")
```

esas son las lineas en las que crea la tabla

```
cursoor.executemany("INSERT INTO USUARIOS VALUES (NULL, ?, ?, ?, ?)" , lista)
```

y esta en la que ingresa los datos de la tupla

https://pastebin.com/V77e8i3k

Ahi está tambien el codigo entero por si hace falta revisar algo mas.
(Esta MUY MAL ORGANIZADO y lo podría haber hecho con class pero cuando me dí cuenta ya era tarde y habria tenido que borrar mucho codigo)

Comment: cuando haces `print(valor)` justo antes del `cursor.executemany`qué te devuelve? que tipo es al hacer también `print(type(valor))`?

Comment: el print simplemente es para que en la terminal me diga el texto ingresado en un Entry de tkinter el cual esta destinado para elegir el nombre de la BBDD

Igualmente ya entendi (a medías) que era lo que pasaba y es que a principios tenia "cursoor.execute" en lugar del executemany y que le faltaba una lista/tupla con valores.

Igualmente ahora me sigue tirando error pero al reves, dice que le dí mas información de la que recibe la base de datos

Ahi arriba modifiqué la publicación original.

Comment: Podrías ingresar ahora que error te arroja la consola?

Comment: `sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 4, and there are 5 supplied`

Y el codigo está tal como en la pregunta original

Comment: Ya pude encontrar cual era el problema, despues de mirar detenidamente me di cuenta que presente la tupla con un sintaxis incorrecto

`lista=["hola1", "hola2", "hola3", "hola4"]`

Cuando realmente debería haberlo presentado así.

`lista=[("hola1", "hola2", "hola3", "hola4")]`